# How to send email from Craft 3 custom plugin?

Tags: emails

I have created custom plugin in Craft 3 and want send email to receiver or site email when user submits a form.

Comment: I am new in craft please guide me where should i keep this code.
Actually my task is -
I have a replacement form that contain some fields. I want to send a mail to the admin with data and attachment Please help me

Comment: Hi Shivam, welcome to Craft SE! Since this is a new question (not an answer to the original question), I'd recommend [starting a new thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to link back to this thread for reference.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Edit: After the migration to Craft 3.1.x you should rather use this Code

```PHP
/**
 * @param string                            $html
 * @param string                            $subject
 * @param array|string|\craft\elements\User $mail
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function sendMail(string $html, string $subject, $mail): bool
{
    return Craft::$app
        ->getMailer()
        ->compose()
        ->setTo($mail)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($html)
        ->send();
}
```

#### Edit: this is my old answer, valid for Craft 3.0.x

This is my code to send emails in Craft 3. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
use craft\mail\Message;

/**
 * @param $html
 * @param $subject
 * @param null $mail
 * @param array $attachments
 * @return bool
 */
private function sendMail($html, $subject, $mail = null, array $attachments = array()): bool
{
    $settings = Craft::$app->systemSettings->getSettings('email');
    $message = new Message();

    $message->setFrom([$settings['fromEmail'] => $settings['fromName']]);
    $message->setTo($mail);
    $message->setSubject($subject);
    $message->setHtmlBody($html);
    if (!empty($attachments) && \is_array($attachments)) {

        foreach ($attachments as $fileId) {
            if ($file = Craft::$app->assets->getAssetById((int)$fileId)) {
                $message->attach($this->getFolderPath() . '/' . $file->filename, array(
                    'fileName' => $file->title . '.' . $file->getExtension()
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    return Craft::$app->mailer->send($message);
}
```

Comment: To avoid the 5 minutes of googling around I just did, you need to add `use craft\mail\Message;` at the top of your file for the `$message = new Message();` call. See https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-mail-message.html

Comment: @natebeaty I suggest you to use a proper IDE. Most of them handle those issues nearly on their own.

Comment: I know you mean well, but your comment comes off as condescending. Even if someone is using a "proper IDE" it's helpful for them to know they need `use craft\mail\Message;` above their class declaration to make this code example work.

Comment: Pretty tough to figure out how to find out what portion of the class documentation to go to when trying to send an email. Couldnt find it there, so here I am.

Comment: I put in a request for edit, but I actually capitalized Craft\Mail when its supposed to be lowercase in the use statement.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the detailed example Robin. 

Although I got a `deprecated` warning on my IDE and it seems recommended to update the `getSettings` from systemSettings. These values should come from the project config. :)

Comment: That's why I said the it's valid for Craft 3.0.X without project config and the first answer is for Craft 3.1 with deprecated system settings