# What's the differences between the Mailer and the Message classes?

Tags: plugin-development, documentation, classes

In the Craft 3 Class Reference (https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3), there are two classes under `craft\mail`:

- Mailer
- Message

I found that I was able to send an email using this:

```
<?php 

use craft\mail\Message;

$message = new Message();
$message->setTo('john@doe.com');
$message->setSubject("Hello world.");
$message->setHtmlBody("Hello world.");
$message->send();
```

But I found in some examples, like [this one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/how-to-send-email-from-craft-3-custom-plugin), that the email could be send using `Craft::$app->mailer->send($message)` instead of `$message->send()`.

What's the difference between the **Mailer** and the **Message** classes? When should I use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both valid options.

`$message->send()` is a wrapper for `Mailer`:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/mail/BaseMessage.php#L41-L50

It will take an optional Mailer parameter.  If one is not passed it, it will default to the default Yii/Craft::$app->mailer and ultimately just call `send()` on it.