# How to send email from Craft 4 custom plugin/module?

Tags: emails, craft4, smtp

I want to send an email using crafts mailer in Craft 4.
I've seen this post:
[How to send email from Craft 3 custom plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23804/how-to-send-email-from-craft-3-custom-plugin)

But now I need this adapted for craft 4.
Unfortunately I did not succeed so much.

I think something like this:

```php
$mail = Craft::$app->mailer;

$mail->template = "My email template. How to use placeholders?";
$mail->send($message); // how do I set up that message?
// where can I set the recipient address?
```

Links: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-mail-mailer.html#public-methods

I want to use the settings I have set in the CP:

[image]

I would be very thankful for an example, as the Craft 4 documentation is a bit to sparse for somebody like me .

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
    $view               = Craft::$app->getView();
    $email              = 'example@example.com'
    $subject            = $view->renderString($messageSubject, $variables, View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);
    $html               = $view->renderTemplate($template,$variables , View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);

    Craft::$app
        ->getMailer()
        ->compose()
        ->setTo($email)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($html)
        ->send();
```

Comment: Sorry to ask again... This looks promising, but I have still some noob questions:
- what is the $template for example? Where can I define those, where can I get that?
- What should the $variables array contain?
The link here: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-mail-mailer.html#public-methods lists some but I still don't get how it works... :s
- $messageSubject is just a string, right?
- What is the `View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE` part?

Comment: @Merc, $template is your twig template path. $variables yes it is contain array. This contain variable you want to pass to your twig template, The View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE is option to identify Craft where they should search your template, so View::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE is means is  using the template folder you use normally. 

if you no need to render from twig template you can just put your html code inside the $html variable.

Comment: Ah perfect. No I don't need a template. 
And thanks for all the other answers. I will try that!

Comment: I tried, for the sake of completeness, to render a twig template in my $html.
But this line fails already: `$view = Craft::$app->getView();` with this error: `\"modules\\commentmodule\\controllers\\View\" not found",` 
Is this related to: https://verbb.io/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-modules#templates > so I need to register views in my controller first? (I will try and report back here, if I find a solution :))
Sorry for all the beginners questions :S

Comment: I think I need to register the views, but I fail...
I register the view like here (https://verbb.io/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-modules#templates) in my `/modules/commentmodule/CommentModule.php`.

I have `/modules/commentmodule/templates/emails/mail.twig` and I try to render it 
`$html = Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('commentmodule/emails/mail.twig', $variables);` – but then it will fail with `Template could not be found`.
 :(

And I try to render that template within
`modules/commentmodule/controllers/MailController.php`